# Jenkins Pipeline fails when triggering a remote job with option "Block Build Until Complete" is enabled

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I created a pipeline which should trigger a job on a different Jenkinsserver.
I use the Remote Trigger Plug-in and I am able to trigger the Job with following statement (currently this is the only statement in my pipeline):

```
triggerRemoteJob enhancedLogging: true, job: 'myJob', maxConn: 1,     remoteJenkinsName: 'MyJenkins'
```

But after the Job is triggered the pipeline tries to connect a job in a job running on localhost which obviously fails.

I tried to disable some options an found that it works if I disable blockBuildUntilComplete.

From the Log I got following with option enabled:

```
##############################################################################    ##################################

  Parameterized Remote Trigger Configuration:

    - job:                     myJob 

    - remoteJenkinsName:       myJenkins

    - parameters:              

    - blockBuildUntilComplete: true

    - connectionRetryLimit:    5

################################################################################################################

Triggering non-parameterized remote job 'http://x.x.x.x:8080/job/myJob'

  Using globally defined 'Credentials Authentication' as user 'myUser' (Credentials ID 'myCredentials')

Triggering remote job now.

CSRF protection is disabled on the remote server.

  Remote job queue number: 47

Remote build started!

  Remote build URL: http://localhost:8080/job/myJob /8/

  Remote build number: 8

Blocking local job until remote job completes.

calling remote without locking...

Connection to remote server failed , waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. URL: http://localhost:8080/job/myJob /8/api/json/, parameters: 

Retry attempt #1 out of 5

Connection to remote server failed , waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. URL: http://localhost:8080/job/myJob /8/api/json/, parameters: 

Retry attempt #2 out of 5

Connection to remote server failed , waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. URL: http://localhost:8080/job/myJob /8/api/json/, parameters: 

Retry attempt #3 out of 5

Connection to remote server failed , waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. URL: http://localhost:8080/job/myJob /8/api/json/, parameters: 

Retry attempt #4 out of 5

Connection to remote server failed , waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. URL: http://localhost:8080/job/myJob /8/api/json/, parameters: 

Retry attempt #5 out of 5

Max number of connection retries have been exeeded.
```

I changed the names and the IP-Adress of my Jenkins-Server.

I must do some steps after my remote job finished which are depending from its results. So I must wait until the job is done.

Is there a way to do this without the block-option or what must I do to get the option working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the released of the plugin and I found an improvement for release 3.0.8 called "Extend POST timeout & avoid re-POST after timeout"
I reviewed the change an since it looked good with regards to our problem I updated our plugin (v3.0.7) to the current version.
Now the error does not appear anymore.